# Best way to use Facebook as site membership system, asp.net mvc 3, using Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Here's how I currently use the Facebook C# SDK, with Facebook Javascript SDK (this is from memory, but I think it's accurate psuedo-code):

```
FbApp = new FacebookApp
Is FbApp.Session null?
  No - they're logged into Facebook, pull profile from DB
    Is profile null?
    Yes - they aren't a member, ask for permission then save their FacebookId, Name, and Email
    No - they're a member
  Yes - they're not logged into Facebook
```

That's really about it. But reading through [the tutorial here](http://ntotten.com/2011/03/facebook-c-sdk-tutorial-getting-started-with-an-asp-net-mvc-3-website-with-javascript-sdk/), I'm wondering if I'm doing something the wrong way? Or a "bad" way? I've been using it this way for around 3 months without issue.

I've read others having issues with Facebook changing their authentication API's, but I've never had any hiccups. The Facebook C# SDK has been updated a few times sine I started using it, but I haven't upgraded yet.

Just want to be sure, what I'm doing is ok or am I heading for a "train wreck"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I think is to understand the Facebook API yourself  ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ ) . Using library will help you but it will make you dependent with the library. Facebook is famous for its frequency of changing API. So depending entirely on a library will likely make your job more stressful ( worse if the library took long to update).

Just my 2 cents

Comment: That's a good point, know of any C#/ASP.NET MVC examples that don't use a library?

Comment: I was using https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk it doesn't have a full api but it has the basic stuff you need to connect to facebook api. And you don't need to use libcurl.dll for this. 

eg.

`

Hope this helps.

Comment: `
var api = new Facebook.FacebookAPI();
api.AccessToken = "accesstoken";
Dictionary<string, string> args = new Dictionary<string, string>();
args["message"] = "this is test message";
args["link"] = "http://www.google.com";
args["picture"] = "http://s.com/a.jpg";
args["name"] = "test name";
args["description"] = "test desc";
applicationArgs["id"] = "appid";
applicationArgs["name"] = "test";
actionArgs["name"] = "action name";
actionArgs["link"] = "http://al.com";
api.Post(string.Format("/{0}/feed", "pageid"), args);`